# How to load two div from two different div (from html) by clicking the same link 

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to click on `a#lanostracasa` to take two different divs from an external `.html` and load it in another two div (the `#fotoCasa` from the external file `havePicture`)( http://frostcode.altervista.org and http://frostcode.altervista.org/db.html for the external HTML.)

I'm going crazy because I see the text in the container while I see it loading, and all the text disappears and no content was loaded.

```
<div id="contAll">
   <div id="fotoCasaHtml"></div>
   <div id="container">
    <p>
    <div id="imgHome"><img class="img"src="images/noimg.png"></div>
          blablablablablablabla
    </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

The link I want to to click:

```
<div id="cssmenu">
<li><a id="lanostracasa"href='#'><span>La Nostra Casa</span></a>
</div>
```

and the JavaScript that doesn't work:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   $( function() {

      $( 'a#lanostracasa' ).click(function() {
         var postData = ''; // you can send any data to ajax file.
         $('#container , #fotoCasaHtml').html('<p>loading</p>');
         $.ajax( {
            url : 'db.html',
            type : 'post',
            data : postData,
            success : function( resp ) {
               $('#container').html($('#lanostracasa-ita' , resp).html());
               $('#fotoCasaHtml').html($('#fotoCasa' , resp).html());
            }
         });
            return false;
      });
   });
   </script>
```

I also use this call in jQuery for the same link but I don't think it affect the JavaScript:

```
$("#cssmenu a#lanostracasa").click(function(){
$('#container').load('db.html #lanostracasa-ita')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have two events bound to the same element that are, by themselves, contradictory.  You cannot bind the same event (click) twice to the same element.  In this case you have a precedence problem that needs to be addressed.  One function is being fired and one is not, choose which one to use.  Furthermore, if you think of this from a logical perspective...what's the point of binding the same event twice?  If ONCLICK you want two things to happen, just put them both in one function.

Also, you must remember that when binding events to elements, the elements themselves must EXIST prior to binding.  I can't see your HTML to verify that your second .click() event is wrapped in a function closure or $(document).ready() but that may also be a source of confusion.